# Flutter Firstore Timestamp now / current date

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Below are all the Firebase timestamp methods that I have used and found handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get a Firestore timestamp (Todays date)

```
Timestamp timestampDate = Timestamp.now();
```

How to set a Timestamp from Datetime

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.now();
Timestamp timestampDate =  Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(someDate.year, someDate.month, someDate.day))
```

How to get the Date object from Timestamp

```
DateTime dateTime = timestampDate.toDate();
```